# Promise is fulfilled on error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, bluebird

Well, I thought I understand Promises already, but seems I am missing something on this...

```
var redisPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  redisClient.on('error', reject);
  redisClient.on('ready', resolve);
}).then(function() {
  // THIS ISN'T CALLED - CORRECT
  log.enabled && log('connected, version: %s', redisClient.server_info.redis_version);
  return redisClient;
}).catch(function() {
  // THIS GETS CALLED - CORRECT
  log('failed connecting to database:', e.message);
});

redisPromise.then(function() {
  log("This shouldn't be called when connection fails");
});
```

For the case when connection to Redis fails I would expect the returned Promise to be rejected. However for some reason it's fulfilled. Am I missing something here?

I am using [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) implementation. Could it be possibly some bug in there ? I kinda doubt that, it all seems very well documented and making sense ... on paper.

**RESOLVED**

Full discussion at https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/156

Comment: I'm curious, what do you want the program to do if it fails to connect to the database? Exit? Send an error page to the user? Try to reconnect? Or you really want it to just log the error and hang around?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chained promises not passing on rejection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371129/chained-promises-not-passing-on-rejection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying answer from GH issue including Domenic's code sample:

Domenic gave the following example: Think of the equivalent synchronous code:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (e) {
  // THIS GETS CALLED - CORRECT
  log('failed connecting to database:', e.message);
}

log('This shouldn't be called when connection fails :/');
```

and you can see why your expectations don't work so well.

To add to Domenic's excellent analog. 
If you want to signal a fail in execution and handle it, you need to rethrow:

```
try {
   ...
} catch (e) {
  // THIS GETS CALLED - CORRECT
  log('failed connecting to database:', e.message);
  throw e;
}
```

In your case:

```
}).catch(function(e) {
  log('failed connecting to database:', e.message);
  throw e;
});
```

If you want to signal the type of exception - throw your own type of failure. The analogy for the possibly unhandled rejection is what happens when you throw in synchronous code and don't handle it. It defaults to log it to the console.

Here is an alternative solution I don't really like:

```
var redisPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  redisClient.on('error', reject);
  redisClient.on('ready', resolve);
}).then(function() {
  log.enabled && log('connected, version: %s', redisClient.server_info.redis_version);
  return redisClient;
});
redisPromise.catch(function() { 
  log('failed connecting to database:', e.message);
});

redisPromise.then(function() { 
  log('This shouldn't be called when connection fails :/');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pasting it here.

Comment: Sure, feel free to ask more questions it creates a good knowledge base :)

Answer (score 1):

`then` creates a new promise in some libraries. My guess would be that bluebird also creates a promise with `catch`. The way you have chained them, `redisPromise` refers to the "catch" promise, and not the first promise. And "catch" is indeed resolved.

If I'm right, this should work as expected:

```
var redisPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  redisClient.on('error', reject);
  redisClient.on('ready', resolve);
});

redisPromise.then(function() {
  // THIS ISN'T CALLED - CORRECT
  log.enabled && log('connected, version: %s', redisClient.server_info.redis_version);
  return redisClient;
}).catch(function() {
  // THIS GETS CALLED - CORRECT
  log('failed connecting to database:', e.message);
});

redisPromise.then(function() {
  log("This shouldn't be called when connection fails");
});
```

Comment: Yeah, `catch` should be alias to `then(null, handler)`. But I think you have point here. I have to fiddle it little bit more, because using it like this, Bluebird propagates that error to top level and outputs to console. I don't like that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't what you want simply

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  redisClient.on('error', reject);
  redisClient.on('ready', resolve);
}).then(function() {
  // THIS ISN'T CALLED - CORRECT
  log.enabled && log('connected, version: %s', redisClient.server_info.redis_version);
  return redisClient;
}).then(function() {
  log("This shouldn't be called when connection fails");
}).catch(function() {
  // THIS GETS CALLED - CORRECT
  log('failed connecting to database:', e.message);
});
```

Which is same as:

```
try {
   var redisClient = ...
   log.enabled && log('connected, version: %s', redisClient.server_info.redis_version);
   log("This shouldn't be called when connection fails");
} 
catch(e) {
   log('failed connecting to database:', e.message);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it gives me some hard time to look at it like sychronous code, but hopefully I will get used to it. After [discussion](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/156) at GH, it makes sense to me now.