# promise returned in .catch() cannot be .catch'ed again?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise

I have something like:

```
var a = somePromise.then(function() {
    throw 1;
})
.catch(function() {
    return new PromiseReturningThing();
});

a.catch(function() {alert('err');});   // inside is never called, although I know there is an error
```

Let's assume that the `PromiseReturningThing()` returns a promise which will itself throw an exception.
With the above code there is no alert showing up. But using this code, it works:

```
var a = new PromiseReturningThing();
a.catch(function() {alert('err');});
```

Is there a fundamental thing I did not understand? I couldn't find any example on the net, but I think that it is possible to return promises in catch-blocks.

`PromiseReturningThing()` is actually PouchDB(), if you're wondering. And the promises in the first snippet are some authentification routines.

I am using Chrome v37.0.2062.120

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Also weird: if I `return null` in the first snippet at the place where `return new PromiseReturningThing();` is, a.catch doesn't throw an `a is undefined` exception in Chrome. Why that?

Comment: Can you reduce the example it should work :)

Comment: I first thought this was a dupe of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371129/chained-promises-not-passing-on-rejection), but as it stands it seems just that your promise implementation is not spec-compliant.

Comment: …or you did some other mistake that is not in the shown code.

Comment: I thought that, too. But actually it works if you do it the way it is supposed to be. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you were right with reducing the example. The actual problem was that my code looked like:

```
var a = somePromise.then(function() {
    throw 1;
})
.catch(function() {
    return new PromiseReturningThing();
});

a.then(function() {
    // here we can't catch the error anymore:
    a.catch(function() {alert('err');});   // inside is never called, although I know there is an error
});
```

The last line should be

```
a.then(function() {
    // ...
}).catch(function() {alert('err');});   // working now
```

Maybe it'll help someone else to be more careful than I was here. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out to reduce my code :)