# Promises: is .done() executed always even if .catch() is?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

## My Promise issue

I am new to `Promises` and I've been reading the [Q Documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), where it says:

> When you get to the end of a chain of promises, you should either return the last promise or end the chain.

I have defined a Promise in my code the `Q.Promise` way, with the following `console.log`s to log out an execution trace:

```
function foo(){
   return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    doSomething()
    .then(function() {
      console.log('1');
      return doSomething1();
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log('2');
      return doSomething2();
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log('3');
      return doSomething3();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('catch!!');
      reject(err);
    })
    .done(function() {
      console.log('done!!');
      resolve();
    });

  });
}
```

In case every `doSomethingN()` executes correctly, everything works as intended and I get the expected trace:

```
1
2
3
done!!
```

**But** in case any of the `doSomethingN()` fails:

`foo()` works correctly, because the error function callback is the one that runs whenever a `reject(err)` occurs:

`foo().then(function() { /* */ }, function(err) { /* this runs! */ });`

And I get the following trace (ie. when `doSomething1()` fails):

```
1
catch!!
done!!
```

### My question

What I thought at first was the following:

> Okay, let's handle the chaining **success** and **failure** in both: `.done()` and `.catch()` methods. If everything goes well `.done()`'s callback will be executed and the promise will be *resolved*. In case there's an error at any point, `.catch()`'s callback will be executed and the promise will be *rejected* - and because of that, `done()` won't be executed.

I think I am missing something about how the `.done()` works... because by having a look at my logging trace, I realized that `.done()` seems to be executing always - whether there is an error and `.catch()` is executed or not - and that is what I wasn't expecting.

So, after that, I removed `.done()`'s callback and now `foo()`:

- works if there's an `error` during the chain execution
- does not work if everything works correctly

What should I reconsider and how could/should I make it work?

Comment: First of all, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: Your problem is not with `done`, but with `catch`. Catching the error means you've handled it, and the promise that is returned from `.catch(…)` - the one you attach `.done()` to - is going to be fulfilled!

Comment: @Bergi I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to explain in your second comment... What's wrong with that `.catch()`?

Comment: It returns a promise that will eventually be fulfilled, which is the reason why your `done` runs even if there was an error. Have a look at [Chained promises not passing on rejection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16371129/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi the link's you've given about the topic are very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider doing this:

```
function foo() {
  // Calling .then() on a promise still return a promise.
  // You don't need Q.Promise here
  return doSomething()
    .then(function(doSomethingResult) {
      console.log('1');
      return doSomething1();
    })
    .then(function(doSomething1Result) {
      console.log('2');
      return doSomething2();
    })
    .then(function(doSomething2Result) {
      console.log('3');
      return doSomething3();
    });
}



foo()
  .then(function(fooResult) {
    console.log(fooResult); // fooResult should be what is returned by doSomething3()
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err); // Can be thrown by any 
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log('I am always executed! error or success');
  });
```

If you want to return a promise, in most cases it does not make much sense to use catch (unless you want to recover potential errors). It never make sense to use `done` in a method returning a promise. You would rather use these methods at the very end of the chain.

Notice that `doSomethingX()` can return either a value, or a promise, it will work the same.

Comment: Nice point out and very neat explained, @SebastienLorber! I have one very last question about where to use `deferreds` or `new Promises`: 
so, I only should be using these (one or another) to do the "setting" inside the function I want a promise to be returned. 
In this case, inside `foo()` you don't need `deferreds` or `new Promises` because that was already done in  every `doSomethingN()` (which already return a promise) and you get these directly by `.then()`... am I right? I think I'm getting how this works...!

Comment: and @SebastienLorber, if any of the `doSomethingN()` function threw a `reject`... it would propagate and would be caught at the `foo().catch()` wouldn't it?

Comment: Also @charliebrownie if your `doSomethingX()` operations do not need to use the previous results to be performed, you can launch them in parallel (using `Q.all([smth1Promise,smth2Promise,smth3Promise]).spread(res1,res2,res3)`...

Answer (score 5):

`catch(cb)` is just an alias for `then(null, cb)`, and you've actually *fixed* an error in `catch`, so flow naturally turned to *success* result in `done`.

If you want to just *decorate* the error in catch, you should rethrow the error afterwards, e.g. proper passthru may look as:

```
catch(function (err) {
   console.log(err);
   throw err;
});
```

Still your example doesn't make much sense. You should never use `done`, when you return a promise. If you want to resolve initialized promise with internally created chain of promises, you should just resolve it as:

```
resolve(doSomething()
  .then(function() {
    console.log('1');
    return doSomething1();
  })
  ....
  .then(function() {
    console.log('N');
    return doSomethingN();
  }));
```

There's no need for internal error handling, leave that to consumer of promise which you return.

And other point. If when creating new promise you know it will be resolved with other one, then there's  no logical reason to create such promise, just reuse one you planned to resolve with. Such error was also coined as [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)

Comment: Very nice. My only question is: What is the difference about wrapping the chain with `resolve()`?

Comment: Difference is same as between `resolve(promise)` and `promise.done(resolve, reject)`. Both will do exactly same thing, still first one is more straightforward :)

Comment: Still creating new promise, as in your example, doesn't make sense, you should just return that chain promise directly.

Comment: yes, absolutely, that chain should return in order to get that promise when calling `foo`. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by resolving promise in your last *then* callback.

```
function foo(){
    return doSomething()
    .then(function() {
      console.log('1');
      return doSomething1();
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log('2');
      return doSomething2();
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log('3');
      return doSomething3();
    })
}
```

Consider using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) for promises. It has many useful features as compared to any other promise library. You may find it difficult to begin it, but once you get hold of it you're going to love it.

Comment: Is it still not working when all doSomethingN calls are resolved ?

Comment: I agree with @Bergi here.

Comment: @KunalKapadia: No, it's "working" as you intended, but your answer still exhibits a bad practise

Comment: Yes @KunalKapadia, I am looking for the right solution. Already had thought about your solution before, but I discarded it for what Bergi is saying.

Comment: @Bergi Agree with you. Eliminated anti-pattern from my code.