# How does the 'catch' work in a native Promise chain?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, promise

Try this piece of code on console tab of Chrome or Firefox

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        reject(10);
    }, 1000)
})

p.then(function(res) { console.log(1, 'succ', res) })
.catch(function(res) { console.log(1, 'err', res) })
.then(function(res) { console.log(2, 'succ', res) })
.catch(function(res) { console.log(2, 'err', res) })
```

The result will be

```
1 "err" 10
2 "res" undefined
```

I've tried many other examples but it seems that the first `then()` returns a promise that always resolves and never rejects. I've tried this on Chrome 46.0.2490.86 and Firefox 42.0. Why does this happen? I thought that `then()` and `catch()` can be chain multiple times?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chained promises not passing on rejection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16371129/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like in the synchronous code:

```
try { 
    throw new Error();
} catch(e) {
    console.log("Caught");
}
console.log("This still runs");
```

Code that runs *after* the exception has been handled will run - this is because *exceptions are an error recovery mechanism*. By adding that catch you signaled that the error has been handled. In the synchronous case we handle this by rethrowing:

```
try { 
    throw new Error();
} catch(e) {
    console.log("Caught");
    throw e;
}
console.log("This will not run, still in error");
```

Promises work similarly:

```
 Promise.reject(Error()).catch(e => {
      console.log("This runs");
      throw e;
 }).catch(e => {
      console.log("This runs too");
      throw e;
 });
```

As a tip - never reject with non-`Error`s as you lose a lot of useful stuff like meaningful stack traces.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this happen? I thought that then() and catch() can be chain multiple times?

@Benjamin is right, +1, but to put it in another way, these are the rules:

- If you add `then` multiple times, you are chaining methods that should be called in sequence, until an exception is thrown. Exceptions in the `then` chain must be handled by `catch` declared after the  `then`. If there's no `catch` after the `then`, this error will be triggered: `Uncaught (in promise) Error(…)`.
- If you add `catch` multiple times, you are chaining methods that should be called when something goes wrong (in the `then` functions before). However, the second `catch` in the chain will only be called if the first one re-throw the exception, and so forth.
- When `catch` is triggered, the chain resumes on the next `then` declared after the `catch`.