# Handling $routeChangeError with .catch()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm doing some basic routing with ngRoute. I define a service that uses `$http` and plug that into `resolve`. Normally I explicitly use `$q` in the service, but this time I'm using the built in `.then` and `.catch`, and it's not working like it normally does. Here's a pared down version of what I've got:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", 
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl: "views/index.html",
                controller: "indexCtrl",
                resolve: {
                    myData: function(myService){
                        return myService.getMyData();
                    }
                }
            })

            .otherwise({
                templateUrl: "views/404.html"
            });
    }]);
```

The service:

```
app.factory("myService", ["$http", "$route", function($http, $route){
    return {
        getMyData: function(){
            return $http.get("www.url.com")
                .then(function(data){
                    return data;
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    return {err: "There was an error"};
                })
        }
    }
}]);
```

And the controller where the error is handled:

```
app.controller("errorCtrl", ["$rootScope", function($rootScope){

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, current, previous, rejection){
        console.log("err", rejection);
    })

}]);
```

And in the view:

```
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="errorCtrl" ng-view>
```

The problem is that the value returned by `catch()` is not being passed to the `rejection` parameter of the `routeChangeError` handler. I would normally pass the data with `deferred.reject(data)`, but I'm at a loss as to why `.catch()` doesn't work the same way. In fact, the `.catch` block doesn't seem to be getting hit at all. If I go into the service and try to break something, this triggers the `routeChangeError` handler in the controller, but not the `catch` block. Just wondering if someone can provide some insight into what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `return` from the `catch`, you have *handled* the error, and the resulting promise will get fulfilled. See also [Chained promises not passing on rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16371129/1048572).

You will need to re-`throw` an error (or return a rejected promise) if you want a rejection:

```
getMyData: function(){
    return $http.get("www.url.com")
    .catch(function(err){
        throw new Error("There was an error");
    })
}
```

(I've also removed the useless `.then(identity)`)

Comment: Outstanding! Works beautifully. Thanks.