# Why do both Promise's then & catch callbacks get called?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have the following code and when it's executed, it returns both "**rejected**" and "**success**":

```
// javascript promise
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  setTimeout(function(){reject()}, 1000)
});
promise
  .catch(function(){console.log('rejected')})
  .then(function(){console.log('success')});
```

Could anyone explain **why success is logged?**

Comment: `catch` plays the same role as in `try...catch`. It catches a rejection, not just taps it. To reach the expected behaviour, you need to return a rejected promise from `catch` - or better, use a single `then` with second callback.

Comment: You want `promise.then(function(){console.log('success');}, function(){console.log('rejected');})` to get either one and never both.

Comment: See also [why .catch().catch() doesn't forward the exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371129/chained-promises-not-passing-on-rejection)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `then` callback gets called because the `catch` callback is before it, not after. The rejection has already been handled by `catch`. If you change the the order (i.e. (`promise.then(...).catch(...)`)), the `then` callback won't be executed.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Methods_2) says that the `.catch()` method "returns a new promise resolving to the return value of the callback". Your catch callback doesn't return anything, so the promise is resolved with `undefined` value.

Answer (score 13):

> Could anyone explain why success is logged?

In short: a `.then` following a `.catch` in a `Promise` chain will always be executed (unless it itself contains errors).

**The theoretical explanation**

Your code is actually just a `Promise` chain which is first executed *synchronously* setting it up to complete *asynchronously* afterwards. The Javascript engine will pass on any `reject()` or `Error` to the first `.then` down the chain with a `reject` callback in it. The reject callback is the second function passed to a `.then`:

```
.then(
function (){
    //handle success
},
function () {
    //handle reject() and Error
})
```

The use of `.catch` is just syntactic suger for:

```
.then(null, function () {
    //handle reject() or Error
})
```

Each of the `.then`'s automatically returns a new `Promise` which can be acted upon by subsequent `.then`'s (or `.catch`'s which are also `.then`'s).

**Visualizing the flow of your promise chain**

You can visualize the flow of your code with the following example:

```
var step1 = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(reject('error in step1'), 1000);
})

var step2 = step1.then(null, function () {

  // do some error handling
  return 'done handling errors'
})

var step3 = step2.then(function () {

  // do some other stuff after error handling
  return 'done doing other stuff'
}, null)

setTimeout (function () {

console.log ('step1: ', step1);
console.log ('step2: ', step2);
console.log ('step3: ', step3);

console.log();
console.log ('Asynchronous code completed')
console.log();
}, 2000);

console.log ('step1: ', step1);
console.log ('step2: ', step2);
console.log ('step3: ', step3);

console.log();
console.log ('Synchronous code completed')
console.log();
```

which at runtime will result in the following output in the console:

```
step1:  Promise { <rejected> 'error in step1' }
step2:  Promise { <pending> }
step3:  Promise { <pending> }

Synchronous code completed

step1:  Promise { <rejected> 'error in step1' }
step2:  Promise { 'done handling errors' }
step3:  Promise { 'done doing other stuff' }

Asynchronous code completed
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who had a successfully resolved promise and a chain ordered like `.then` > `.catch`, but still had both your `then` and `catch` called, **it may be because your `then` had an error-throwing bug that you can't see unless you explicitly console the error in your `catch`**.  That's one of my pet-peeves with Promises absorbing errors even in strict mode.

```
const promise = new Promise(resolve => resolve())
.then(() => {
    console.log('then');
    not.defined = 'This causes the catch to fire even though the original promise resolved successfully.';
})
.catch((e) => {
    console.log('catch');
    // console.error(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For me `catch()` was being called after a succesful promise, and no errors in `.then()`.

The reason was, that I listened to a value that changes with the successful promise, and ran a method.

This method was throwing a silent error, because it was being counted as part of the promise.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Timar, For me the reason catch was being called is that "then" contains an exception code. so after executing "then" normally and when it reaches the exception code, it handles the exception in "catch" xD