# Can both a then() and catch() clause fire or is it just one or the other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Is there ever a case where both `then()` and `catch()` will fire?

```
read(start).then(() => {
  console.log('DONE:', h.addCommas(data));
}).catch((err)=>{
  console.log('ERROR:');
  console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: what if the _then_ code raises an exception?

Comment: ^ that would be the reason. (Or if it returns a rejected promise.)

Comment: you can use `.finally()` if you want to react no matter what was called

Comment: The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise. so whenever code written inside the promise raise exception then catch() method will fire so in this case both method will call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do both Promise's then & catch callbacks get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069638/why-do-both-promises-then-catch-callbacks-get-called)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both can fire.

**Case 1**: `doSomething().then(successHandler).catch(errorHandler)` - if `doSomething` is successful and `successHandler` throws, then `errorHandler` will fire (otherwise it won't).

**Case 2**: `doSomething().catch(errorHandler).then(successHandler)` - if `doSomething` throws and `errorHandler` doesn't throw, then `successHandler` will fire (otherwise it won't).