# Backbone with Promise.js or pure jQuery to resolve promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, promise

I've to manage a project made with Backbone.js. The project was first released in 2013. At the moment I try to figure out what they did before.

I found out that they use quite often the [Promise.js](https://www.promisejs.org/) libery to communicate with the ReST-Server like the example underneath

```
run: function () {
    if (this.initialAppViewMethod) {
        Promise.resolve(this.model.get('session').fetch())
            .catch(this.showLoginView.bind(this))
            .then(this.initMainView.bind(this));
    }
},
```

I've been wondering if there is a certain reason why they have used Promise.js instead the already used jquery.js liberay to do promises?

BTW: How can I convert this script to use pure jQuery functionallity?

Comment: Because jQuery "promises" are [not pure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23744612/1048572)?

Comment: So if I understand this correct it is saver to use Promise.js as long as I use jQuery < 3.0 because jQuery don't handle promises always correct?

Comment: @FelixFaltin only if you use code that needs compliant promises. Otherwise, there are no reasons.

Comment: Well, jQuery 3 did fix *some* issues, but plain promises are still easier to work with.

Comment: @Bergi but seeing the example in the question, there are no apparent reasons.

Comment: @EmileBergeron uh, a `.catch()` that works like expected looks like a very good reason to me? Although I have no idea what this particular usage is supposed to do

Comment: @Bergi why? jQuery and Backbone (`error` callback) already provides that. That's a genuine question, what's the difference between jQuery 3 `catch` and Promises `catch`? What's better then say the Backbone `error` callback?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Ah, I missed that they added `.catch` to jQuery 3 as well. But those definitely are better than `error` callbacks, especially because they [chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371129/chained-promises-not-passing-on-rejection). Notice that `initMainView` is *always* called (unless `showLoginView` throws), quite unlike the callbacks in your answer.

Comment: @Bergi you're making me doubt myself, but wouldn't the `showLoginView` be called only if the `fetch` fails (promise rejected) and `initMainView` called only if the `fetch` succeed? Yeah chaining is definitely nice, but provided by the jqXHR by default.

Comment: @EmileBergeron this was also my thought. That is is a kind of if-else statement.

Comment: @EmileBergeron No, `initMainView` is called whenever the `fetch(…).catch(…)` fulfills. See also [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371129/chained-promises-not-passing-on-rejection) I linked above and maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why someone might use Promise.js with Backbone could be to integrate easily with another lib but without the code, it's only speculations.

As [mentionned by Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773473/backbone-with-promise-js-or-pure-jquery-to-resolve-promises#comment68771084_40773473):

> Because jQuery "promises" are [not pure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744612/1048572)?

This was [fixed in jQuery 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23744774/1218980).

---

Backbone async functions like [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) uses [jQuery's `ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in the background and it returns a jqXHR object.

> The jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object returned by `$.ajax()` as of
>   jQuery 1.5 is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest
>   object.
>
> [it] implement the
>   Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and
>   behavior of a Promise (see [Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information).

Also, you could use Backbone async functions callbacks and options directly:

```
run: function () {
    if (this.initialAppViewMethod) {
        this.model.get('session').fetch({
            context: this,
            error: this.showLoginView,
            success: this.initMainView
        });
    }
},
```

It would be enough.

Comment: Thanks for that. At the moment I get an error within the _initMainView_ that this is unknow.
    initMainView: function() {
        this.appView = new sand.ApplicationView({
            model: this.model
    });

Comment: @FelixFaltin if you have a new problem which you can't solve, please ask a new question.