# Need to keep promise result in a variable for Nodejs mssql validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-mssql

```
    let RetrieveFromDb=(queryStr) =>
{
    let sql=require('mssql');
    let config={
        server:'127.0.0.1',
        database:'TestDB',
        user:'user',
        password:'user',
    };
    let dbConn=new sql.Connection(config);
    return dbConn.connect().then(function (){
        let request=new sql.Request(dbConn);
        return request.query(queryStr)
        .then(function(recordset)
        {
            return recordset;
            dbConn.close();

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            dbConn.close();
        });
    }).catch(function (err)  {
        console.log(err);
    });
};


RetrieveFromDb("Select FirstName from User where UserID='1'").then(function(x){console.log(x[0].FirstName);});//console is displying the FirstName value from DB
RetrieveFromDb("Select FirstName from User where UserID='1'").then(res=>{console.log(res[0].FirstName)});//console is displying the FirstName value from DB
```

Above two function calls returning values to console, but I want to keep the result of RetrieveFromDb() to a variable, so that I can compare with other data for validation.

Let's say if var `actualFirstname=RetrieveFromDb(myquery);` then I'll compare `if(actualFirstname===expectedFirstName)` or not.

Comment: [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return): _"When a `return` statement is called in a function, the execution of this function is stopped."_

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you please suggest how can I improve the code , avoiding returns, to achieve my objective of getting data from DB.   I added return since without adding return it was returning 'undefined'. please help

Comment: You have to move the `dbConn.close();` before/above the `return recordset;` otherwise you're not closing the db connection

Comment: Notice that you [should use `.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) and [will need to rethrow the exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371129/chained-promises-not-passing-on-rejection) instead of just logging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are a method of code synchronization, so you have to treat their operations as asynchronous and use the values that you get when the promise resolves. There is no way to do:

```
var actualFirstName = RetrieveFromDb(myquery);
actualFirstName === expectedFirstName;
```

Instead, you have to do the comparison when the promise resolves:

```
RetrieveFromDb(myquery).then(data => {
  data.actualFirstName === expectedFirstName;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,  I have geen going round in circles for days trying to get my head around the async nature of the code.  For me the lightbulb moment is that you have to set the variable value as part of the callback/promise stack (i.e. assign it within the function)  My background is Excel, VBA, Sequel Server, PHP oop, C#.  In all of these languages a function is something which runs a discreet piece of code and returns a value which is then assigned to the object on the left of the equasion.

```
function myFunc(){ return 'Hello World'}

var myvar =   myFunc() // sets myvar to 'Hello World'
```

In the land on Node you have to do the assignement **IN** the function

```
function myFunc(){ myvar = 'Hello world'}
```

So to get data from the database:

```
fetchFromDB('Select top 10 * from x',(err,res) =>{ myvar1 = res})
fetchFromDB('Select top 10 * from Y',(err,res) =>{ myvar2 = res})
```