# I was going through MDN docs on Promises And came up with an example which i am not able to understand.Can Anyone explain the flow to me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, es6-promise

the promise gets resolved CB of then runs then it throws a rejected promise after that catch block runs so why the other then ran after that? i am not able to understand the flow behind it does catch also return a new promise?

code-

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    // Makes .then() return a rejected promise
    throw new Error('Oh no!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('onRejected function called: ' + error.message);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("I am always called even if the prior then's promise rejects");
  })
```

output-
I am always called even if the prior then's promise rejects

onRejected function called: Oh no!

Comment: Yes, the `catch()` also [returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#syntax)

Comment: and `.catch()` handles the rejection so the promise it returns is not a rejected one, but a fulfilled one

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371129/chained-promises-not-passing-on-rejection

Comment: Once you are in `Promise` realm you will always be returned a `Promise`.  So both `.catch()` and `.then()` returns a promise. What they return is all about what the provided callback returns. You may do a `.catch(e => (handleError(e), Promise.resolve(3)))` and continue with another `.then()` stage.

Answer (score 1):

Both `then()` and `catch()` methods return a promise and the promise they return depends on two things:

- what happens to the original promise on which they are called?
- What is returned from their callback function?

The last `then()` method is called on the promise returned by the `catch()` method and as the `catch()` method, in your code, implicitly returns undefined, the promise returned by the `catch()` method is resolved with the value of `undefined` which then invokes the `then()` method.

If you want to stop the execution of the last `then()` method, then you need to reject the promise returned by the `catch()` method.
This can be done by either rethrowing the error or returning a rejected promise.

---

Your code is executed as described below:

1. `Promise.resolve()` returns a resolved promise
2. Resolved promise in step 1 leads to the invocation of the `Promise.resolve().then(...)` method's callback function

   - As the callback function of `Promise.resolve().then(...)` throws an error, the promise returned by the `then()` method is rejected with the error object as the rejection reason.
3. As the promise returned by the `then()` method in step 2 is rejected, it leads to the invocation of the `catch()` method's callback function.

   - Callback function of the `catch()` method logs the error
   - As there is no explicit return statement in the callback function of the `catch()` method, the callback method implicitly returns `undefined`.
   - The promise returned by the `catch()` method is resolved with the return value of its callback function, i.e. `undefined`
4. As the promise returned by the `catch()` method is resolved, it invokes the callback function of the last `then()` method

Comment: why the last then console.log() ran before the catch one ?

Comment: `console.error` in the `catch()` method is executed _before_ the `console.log` in the last `then()` method.

Comment: it didn't run **before** the catch one

Comment: i ran it on this site https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3x52gcwsz
I am always called even if the prior then's promise rejects

onRejected function called: Oh no!
this was the result but here on run code snippet it works exactly the same way you explained.

Comment: thans a lot your your help.

Comment: `catch()` method's callback function will execute before the last `then()` method's callback. That difference in output is probably because `console.error` writes to `stderr` whereas `console.log` writes to `stdout`. Try changing `console.error` to `console.log`.